# How To Fetch And Display Multiple Rows?

Tags: php, model, module, fetch, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento which is on the zend framework and the following code currently outputs the first row matching the criteria `is_read != 1', 'is_remove != 1'`. I need to modify this code to output the last 4 table rows that matches said criteria. I tried a few things but none worked. Please Help!

> ModuleName/Model/Resource/

```
public function loadLatestNotice(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox $object)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->order($this->getIdFieldName() . ' DESC')
        ->where('is_read != 1')
        ->where('is_remove != 1')
        ->limit(1);
    $data = $adapter->fetchRow($select);

    if ($data) {
        $object->setData($data);
    }

    $this->_afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}
```

Here are some other codes that are used...

> ModuleName/Model/

```
 public function loadLatestNotice()
{
    $this->setData(array());
    $this->getResource()->loadLatestNotice($this);
    return $this;
}
```

> ModuleName/Block/

```
public function getLatestNotice()
{
    return  $this->_getHelper()
        ->getLatestNotice()->getTitle();
}
```

> Template/

```
href="<?php echo $latestNoticeUrl ?>" onclick="this.target='_blank';"><?php echo $this->getLatestNotice() ?>
```

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Magneto, but seems like you are setting a limit on your query (see the `limit(1)` function you are using)

Comment: 1st of all Happy New Year!, I prob should have mentioned that changing the limit is the first thing i tried, which didn't produce the results i need. From what i understand it is required, but i also need to do something else for it it actually display more than the current 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself, by using the following method. 
The first thing i tried to produce is 4 notification table rows instead of 1, is to change `->limit(1);` to `->limit(4);` and `$adapter->fetchRow($select);` to `$adapter->fetchAll($select);`. The issue is, the solution requires more than just changing these 2 values.

> ModuleName/Model/Resource/

```
public function loadLatestNotice(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox $object)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->order($this->getIdFieldName() . ' DESC')
        ->where('is_read != 1')
        ->where('is_remove != 1')
        ->limit(4);
    $data = $adapter->fetchAll($select);

    if ($data) {
        $object->setData($data);
    }

    $this->_afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}
```

After changing this, the template will stop outputting information, In order for the template to output the new array, you must duplicate some code and remove `->getTitle()` line in the block file, then change a few line of codes in the template .phtml file as follows.

> ModuleName/Block/

```
public function getNewFuncName()
{
return  $this->_getHelper()
    ->getLatestNotice();
}
```

> Template/

```
<?php
$notice = $this->getNewFuncName();
foreach ($notice as $item) {
foreach ($item as $value) {
echo '<div class="notemssg"><p id="notetitle" href='.$value['url'].' >'.$value['title'].'</p><p id="notedate">'.$value['date_added'].'</p></div>';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Changing the code to properly call and display the array will result it 4 table rows being displayed. the code can be modified to be used and any way you would like to display the info on the fronted.

Hope this helps Someone!